# Responsive Wordpress theme images fix

Tags: php, wordpress, responsive-design

I am building responsive theme for Wordpress and i ran into a trouble with responsive images.  The thing is that i need to alter the size of the image that are inside the content. My logic does say that i should use filter for that, but i couldn't find one to target images specifically. 
My first thought was to use a JS [lib](http://filamentgroup.com/examples/responsive-images/) for that but this particular one wants to get the name of both big and small images and since my website is using some custom media sizes i didnt find a way to properly get the name of the small image.

The other way is to use css

```
img {
 max-width: 100%;
}
```

but again what i need to do is to remove the width and height attribute from img tag.

So basically both methods require me to go through content and parse out image tags and then replace them with newly generated ones.

I did some digging in different plugins sources and found that they filter the_content and just use regex to find img tags and replace them with new.

So i am looking for a solution to make this work the right way because i have a feeling that going through whole content just to replace images isnt the right way.
if there isn't any better way to do it could someone please help me with the code (especially regex) to solve my little problem. basically i need to search out img tags and remove width and height attributes.

Comment: I don't really no anything about responsive themes as I'm not a web developer but I noticed Bruce Lawson literally just tweeted a blog post he's written on exactly this subject. [Check it out here](http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2011/notes-on-adaptive-images-yet-again/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS will easily override the inline img tag, just use

```
#.. img{

height:auto;
width:100%;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just stick this in your functions.php and you should be good to go (no width or height in thumbnail images or images added through editor)

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );

function remove_thumbnail_dimensions( $html ) {
$html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html );
return $html;
}
```